# The reduce() function has been confusing me

Tags: python

I have been trying to learn the *reduce* function. In the beginning, it seemed pretty simple and straightforward.

I am trying to convert [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) to integer. There were a few more conditions in the lambda function, but they are left out here. Here's the code:

```
 rit = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
 reduce(lambda x, y: rit[x] + rit[y], s)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 2
    return reduce(lambda x, y: rit[x] + rit[y], list(s))
Line 4 in <lambda> (Solution.py)
    return reduce(lambda x, y: rit[x] + rit[y], list(s))
Line 4 in romanToInt (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().romanToInt(param_1)
Line 28 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 39 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

What is the explanation?

I am expecting the sum of this number, after referencing the dict,
but I end up with this error.

Comment: What are you trying to do? sum all the values inside your dictionary? what is `s`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce _"The left argument, `x`, is the accumulated value and the right argument, `y`, is the update value from the iterable."_ so if you are trying to sum things, x and y should both be numbers, but you are trying to use them as keys to a dictionary which has string keys.

Comment: Note that this approach of summing each character won't work with the values IV, XC, etc.

Comment: @Learningisamess Looks like it's trying to calculate the value of a roman numeral. `rit` is the values of each Roman digit, and `s` would be a numercal like `XVII`.

Comment: I was trying to calculate roman to integer, there were few more conditions in the lambda function, I chose to skip for keeping it short.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is the running accumulated value, not an element of `s`, while `y` is the next element of `s`. You shouldn't use `x` as an index into the dictionary, just add to it directly. It's helpful to use more meaningful names, like `acc` and `item`.

You also need to provide an initial value of the accumulator. If not given, it defaults to the first element of `s`, but `s` contains characters, not numbers.

```
rit = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
s = 'XVII'
num = reduce(lambda acc, item: acc + rit[item], s, 0)
print(num) # prints 17
```